# Can not set font to desired type

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextview, uifont

I have a "textView" that is located inside a "tableViewCell" in a "tableView".

In the main "storyboard" I set the font of the "textView" to my desired color at size 17.

However, every time I run the program the font shows up black and size 'system' 12, which is the default for a "textView".

I have tried to set my font programmatically through "cellForRowAtIndexPath", and through the "Main StoryBoard" but neither seem to work.

Here is where i try to set the font programmatically. I have also tried to set it through the storyboard.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: FeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("clickCells", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

        cell.clickCaption.font = UIFont(name: "system", size: 18)
        cell.clickCaption.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: yes, I added where I try to set the font programmatically, but no matter what it always shows up as the default font.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
cell.clickCaption.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)
```

Pretty sure that there is no font called "system"... check this:

[Which fonts are available in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320664/which-fonts-are-available-in-ios-9)